# Is there any way to search for text in the *body* of a message in Sparrow on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, search, email

Sparrow for iPhone seems to only search the same fields that the Mail app does: from, to, subject, or all of them.

Given that gmail (sparrow's data source) and the sparrow Mac app both allow full text searches, and presumably the "work" is done on the gmail server side, it seems odd that you can't search the body of messages.

Am I missing something?   If not, does anyone know if this might be planned for a future release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, and at least with Sparrow for iPhone 1.3.2 build 507.11, *All* does not refer to FROM+TO+SUBJECT, but all available fields, including the email body.